# how to get IP address of a computers that is directly connected to my PC

Tags: c++, networking, ip-address

I'm trying to write a function that can get me the IP adress (and the name of the device as bonus) of devices that are in my network, the network is gonna be a direct connection between two computers using Ethernet cable or creating an access point (using wi-fi)

I tried to search about how to do it but it seems like I need to listen to the network or something which seems to be difficult.

hope you can guide me to what I should do or read to get started.

Note: I'm using Windows on both computers.

Edited:
P.S: I need the IP Address so I can send a message to the other computer using winsock in a Client/Server program I wrote. 
can't I make the server send its IP to the client or the opposite ?

Comment: Generally you're going to have to know either a device name or an address to establish a connection. It is possible to probe an entire address range or to listen passively but both methods have issues. This seems like a case of looking for answers in the wrong place. Try to change something else about the situation so you can have a fixed name or address with which to connect.

Comment: @ChrisRyding I wrote two programmes (Client/server) that can Send/receive a message but you got to know the IP Address of the receiver.  isn't there a way that I write one of these programs send the computer information to the network so the other program can receive it or something ?

Comment: You can join a multicast group if both platforms support it. You can probe the entire address range and look for a response, but this is slow and it may be difficult to deal with multiple devices. You can watch the ARP cache on one side and have the other send spurious ARP requests but have the same multi-device problems. It's not that this is an impossible issue, just that there's probably a better way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your software is running on both machines, you can have one (or both) machines send out a particular broadcast (or, if you prefer, multicast) UDP packet on a specific port.  Your program should also be listening on that same port.  When it receives that packet (using recvfrom()), recvfrom()'s fifth argument will contain the IP address of the machine that sent the packet, i.e. the IP address you want.

(If OTOH your software is not running on the remote machine, you'll need to use some more general-purpose discovery mechanism such as mDNS or LLDP -- hopefully you won't have to do that, though, as it's a good deal more complicated)

Comment: thanks, I think this is what I needed.  P.S: you might mean the fourth argument of recvform, because from what I just read the 5th argument is pointer to the size of the buffer of the 4th argument.

Comment: Fifth argument looks correct to me:  int recvfrom(SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags, struct sockaddr *from, int *fromlen);